# @PermitAll annotation is ignored in Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am currently working on a simple app which utilizes a monolithic architecture, in which I am using a basic form of role based authentication (using self-signed JWTs). The setup and issuing of the tokens works fine.

I am using Spring Security. By default, I want everything to be locked down, that is, if I want to specifically enable access to an endpoint method, I would like to do so **only** in the endpoint, using the @PermitAll annotation.

However, that annotation is ignored, so I have to specify the public endpoints manually in the Spring Config, specifically, in the "requestMatchers". I don't like this solution, as I have to write the endpoint paths twice (in the controller, and in the security config):

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                    auth
                            .requestMatchers("/register", "/login").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(jwt -> jwt.decoder(jwtDecoder())))
            .exceptionHandling(ex ->
                    ex.authenticationEntryPoint(new BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                            .accessDeniedHandler(new BearerTokenAccessDeniedHandler()))
            .build();
}
```

Furthermore, the endpoint looks as follows:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthController {

    private final AuthService authService;

    @GetMapping
    public String foo() {
        return "Only authenticated users can use this";
    }

    // @PermitAll is ignored here, manual config is needed
    @PostMapping("login")
    public String login(@RequestBody LoginDto loginDto) {
        return authService.login(loginDto);
    }

    // @PermitAll is ignored here, manual config is needed
    @PostMapping("register")
    public String register(@RequestBody RegisterDto registerDto) {
        return authService.register(registerDto);
    }

}
```

The security config class is annotated with the following annotations:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
```

*Note: Mind you, all other annotations (e.g. Secured/RolesAllowed, ...) are working as expected.*

Comment: Could you change `@PostMapping("login")` to `@PostMapping("/login")` also for register ? It will help you

Comment: @AndreiLisa Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, that did not help.

Comment: what is the request path that you are trying to access ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this has to do with the default behaviour of spring security's `SecurityFilterChain`.
You haven't provided your non-working `SecurityFilterChain` configuration but I'll assume the `authorizeHttpRequests` lambda looked something like this:

```java
authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated())
```

Since spring dispatches the call [to the first `FilterChain` that matches](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture/) and you probably defined your `FilterChain` as requiring authentication for every endpoints (if the assumption above holds), then regardless of what you annotated your endpoint with, access will be denied.

I don't think it's particularly bad practice to duplicate your public endpoint's paths but if you don't want to do that, you can use a common prefix to all your public endpoints and match that prefix with wildcards in your security configuration:

```java
authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                     auth.requestMatchers("/your-prefix/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
```